# Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets - Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling, provisioning-profile

I recently started to develop an Apple Watch App. If I try to submit my Application to the AppStore I get the following Error:

[image]

The first one is for my "Applications/Appname.app" and the second one for my "Applications/Appname.app/PlugIns/WatchKitExtensionName.appex".

Can anybody help me?

Thank you for your advice and attention!

Answer (score 0):

Your "App group Identifier" is probably not correctly defined in one of the following three provisioning profiles. Make sure you've defined your App group ID and added them to each provisioning profiles and their corresponding AppID's in developer.apple.com. Also make sure App grouping is enabled for every one of them.

- Application's provisioning profile
- WatchKit Extension's provisioning profile
- Watckit App's provisioning profile